# float vlaue returns 0?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4, xcode4

Ok this is going to be a bit long and i apologize for that but here it is.

The app I am working on is a "Fitness" app that calculates body fat percentages. It has a male side and a female side.

i have 3 classes for male and 3 classes for female.

```
 maleBFCinput 
 maleBFCdata
 maleBFCresults

 femaleBFCinput
 femaleBFCdata
 femaleBFCresults
```

In the input classes, i have textfields for user input, calculations are made inside "maleBFCinput.m" . Once the calculations have been made, they are transfered to the "data" class then onto the "results" class.

The male side works flawless. The female side however is where the problem is. on the results.xib i have 7 lables. age / height / weight / minweight / maxweight / bodyfat / allowed body fat .

the "bodyfat" label on the female results is returning 0 . using the same technique i used to calculate the male side, which works as it is intended, i keep getting 0.

I am using floats on the input screen to hold all of the "tempvalues" from smaller calculations that then go into the "bodyfat calculation".

below are small snipets of code i have.

femaleBFCinput.h

```
    UITextField *ageInput;
    UITextField *heightInput;
    UITextField *weightInput;
    UITextField *hips1Input;
    UITextField *hips2Input;
    UITextField *hips3Input;
    UITextField *neck1Input;
    UITextField *neck2Input;
    UITextField *neck3Input;
    UITextField *abdomen1Input;
    UITextField *abdomen2Input;
    UITextField *abdomen3Input;

    float heightFactor;
    float weightFactor;
    float abHipsFactor;
    float abFactor;
    float neckFactor;
    float minWeight;
    float maxWeight;
    float maxBodyFatPercentage;
    float abdomenAvg;
    float neckAvg;
    float hipsAvg;
    float abHipsValue;
    float abNeckSubValue;
    float bodyFatPercentage;
    float circumferenceValue;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *ageInput;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *weightInput;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *heightInput;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *abdomen1Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *abdomen2Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *abdomen3Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *neck1Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *neck2Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *neck3Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *hips1Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *hips2Input;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *hips3Input;

- (float) getMinWeight;
- (float) getMaxWeight;
- (float) getCircumferenceValue;
- (float) getMaxBodyFatPercentage;
- (float) getAbdomenAvg;
- (float) getNeckAvg;
- (float) getAbHipsFactor;
- (float) getBodyFatPercentage;
- (float) getHipsAvg;
```

femaleBFCinput.m

```
// Get Abdomen Avg..

- (float) getAbdomenAvg
{
    float abdomen1Float = [abdomen1Input.text floatValue];
    float abdomen2Float = [abdomen2Input.text floatValue];
    float abdomen3Float = [abdomen3Input.text floatValue];

    (abdomenAvg = ((abdomen1Float + abdomen2Float + abdomen3Float) / 3));

    return abdomenAvg;
}

// Get Neck Avg..

- (float) getNeckAvg
{
    float neck1Float = [neck1Input.text floatValue];
    float neck2Float = [neck2Input.text floatValue];
    float neck3Float = [neck3Input.text floatValue];

    (neckAvg = ((neck1Float + neck2Float + neck3Float) / 3));
    return neckAvg;
}

// Get Hips Avg..

- (float) getHipsAvg
{
    float hips1Float = [hips1Input.text floatValue];
    float hips2Float = [hips2Input.text floatValue];
    float hips3Float = [hips3Input.text floatValue];

    (hipsAvg = ((hips1Float + hips2Float + hips3Float) / 3));
    return hipsAvg;
}

//-----Get AbNeck Factor----------------------------------

- (float) getAbHipsFactor
{
    float abTempAvg = [self getAbdomenAvg];
    float hipsTempAvg = [self getHipsAvg];

    (abHipsValue = (abTempAvg + hipsTempAvg));

    return abHipsValue;
}


//----Get Circumference Value-----------------------------

- (float) getCircumferenceValue
{

    (circumferenceValue = (abHipsValue - neckAvg));

    return circumferenceValue;
}

// Get Body Fat Percentage..

- (float) getBodyFatPercentage
{
    float circumferenceTempValue = [self getCircumferenceValue];
    float heightTempValue = [heightInput.text floatValue];


    if (heightTempValue >= 58.00 && heightTempValue <= 58.49) {
        if (circumferenceTempValue >= 45.00 && circumferenceTempValue <= 45.49) {bodyFatPercentage = 19;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 45.50 && circumferenceTempValue <= 45.99) {bodyFatPercentage = 20;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 46.00 && circumferenceTempValue <= 46.49) {bodyFatPercentage = 21;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 46.50 && circumferenceTempValue <= 46.99) {bodyFatPercentage = 21;}

 else if (heightTempValue >= 77.50 && heightTempValue <= 77.99) {
        if (circumferenceTempValue >= 53.50 && circumferenceTempValue <= 53.99) {bodyFatPercentage = 19;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 54.00 && circumferenceTempValue <= 54.49) {bodyFatPercentage = 20;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 54.50 && circumferenceTempValue <= 54.99) {bodyFatPercentage = 20;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 55.00 && circumferenceTempValue <= 55.49) {bodyFatPercentage = 21;}

        etc..
        etc.. (theres about 4000ish lines of if / else if statements in here so i just pasted a few so you see what i have)

        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 77.50 && circumferenceTempValue <= 77.99) {bodyFatPercentage = 45;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 78.00 && circumferenceTempValue <= 78.49) {bodyFatPercentage = 46;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 78.50 && circumferenceTempValue <= 78.99) {bodyFatPercentage = 46;}
        else if (circumferenceTempValue >= 79.00 && circumferenceTempValue <= 79.49) {bodyFatPercentage = 47;}
    }

    return bodyFatPercentage;

}



- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    FemaleBFCresults *femaleBFCresults = [[FemaleBFCresults alloc] initWithNibName:@"FemaleBFCresults" bundle:nil];

    FemaleBFCdata *femaleBFCData = [[FemaleBFCdata alloc] init];
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata = femaleBFCData;

    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.ageInput = ageInput.text;
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.heightInput = heightInput.text;
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.weightInput = weightInput.text;

    NSString *minWeightString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [self getMinWeight]];
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.minWeight = minWeightString;
    [minWeightString release];

    NSString *maxWeightString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [self getMaxWeight]];
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.maxWeight = maxWeightString;
    [maxWeightString release];

    NSString *maxBodyFatString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [self getMaxBodyFatPercentage]];
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.maxBodyFat = maxBodyFatString;
    [maxBodyFatString release];

    NSString *bodyFatString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [self getBodyFatPercentage]];
    femaleBFCresults.femaleBFCdata.bodyFat = bodyFatString;
    [bodyFatString release];


    femaleBFCresults.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:femaleBFCresults animated:YES];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [femaleBFCresults release];

}
```

femaleBFCdata.h

```
@interface FemaleBFCdata : NSObject {


    NSString *ageInput;
    NSString *heightInput;
    NSString *weightInput;
    NSString *neckAvg;
    NSString *abAvg;
    NSString *hipsAvg;
    NSString *abHipFactor;
    NSString *bodyFat;
    NSString *maxBodyFat;
    NSString *minWeight;
    NSString *maxWeight;
    NSString *circumference;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ageInput;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *heightInput;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *weightInput;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *neckAvg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *abAvg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *hipsAvg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *abHipFactor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bodyFat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *maxBodyFat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *minWeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *maxWeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *circumference;
```

femaleBFCdata.m

```
@synthesize ageInput;
@synthesize heightInput;
@synthesize weightInput;
@synthesize neckAvg;
@synthesize abAvg;
@synthesize hipsAvg;
@synthesize abHipFactor;
@synthesize bodyFat;
@synthesize maxBodyFat;
@synthesize minWeight;
@synthesize maxWeight;
@synthesize circumference;

- (void)dealloc {

    self.ageInput = nil;
    self.heightInput = nil;
    self.weightInput = nil;
    self.neckAvg = nil;
    self.abAvg = nil;
    self.hipsAvg = nil;
    self.abHipFactor = nil;
    self.bodyFat = nil;
    self.maxBodyFat = nil;
    self.minWeight = nil;
    self.maxWeight = nil;
    self.circumference = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

femaleBFCresults.h

```
@interface FemaleBFCresults : UIViewController {

    FemaleBFCdata *femaleBFCdata;
    UILabel *displayAge;
    UILabel *displayHeight;
    UILabel *displayWeight;
    UILabel *displayBodyFat;
    UILabel *displayMaxBodyFat;
    UILabel *displayMinWeight;
    UILabel *displayMaxWeight;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FemaleBFCdata *femaleBFCdata;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayAge;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayHeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayWeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayBodyFat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayMaxBodyFat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayMinWeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *displayMaxWeight;

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

femaleBFCdata.m

```
@synthesize femaleBFCdata;
@synthesize displayAge;
@synthesize displayHeight;
@synthesize displayWeight;
@synthesize displayBodyFat;
@synthesize displayMaxBodyFat;
@synthesize displayMinWeight;
@synthesize displayMaxWeight;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.displayAge.text = femaleBFCdata.ageInput;
    self.displayHeight.text = femaleBFCdata.heightInput;
    self.displayWeight.text = femaleBFCdata.weightInput;
    self.displayBodyFat.text = femaleBFCdata.bodyFat;
    self.displayMaxBodyFat.text = femaleBFCdata.maxBodyFat;
    self.displayMinWeight.text = femaleBFCdata.minWeight;
    self.displayMaxWeight.text = femaleBFCdata.maxWeight;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [displayAge dealloc];
    [displayHeight dealloc];
    [displayWeight dealloc];
    [displayBodyFat dealloc];
    [displayMaxBodyFat dealloc];
    [displayMinWeight dealloc];
    [displayMaxWeight dealloc];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Like i said the male classes which are done the exact same way this is works perfect. but on the female classes i keep getting 0 return on my results class and i cant seem to figure out why. I've been working on this for a few months now. i took a few weeks off and i thought i had this working before i took a break but i guess i didnt. Does any one have any ideas that would help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i got it working by rounding all of the "averages" that i was calculating before i got to the "bodyfatcalculations"

```
 - (float)getabHipAvg {
     float ab1 = [abdomen1Input.text floatValue];
     float ab2 = [abdomen2Input.text floatValue];
     float ab3 = [abdomen3Input.text floatValue];
     float hip1 = [hips1Input.text floatValue];
     float hip2 = [hips2Input.text floatValue];
     float hip3 = [hips3Input.text floatValue];

     (abHipAvg = (((ab1+ab2+ab3)/3)+((hip1+hip2+hip3)/3)));
     abHipAvg = roundf(abHipAvg * 2.0f) / 2.0f;

     return abHipAvg; }

 - (float)getneckAvg {
     float neck1 = [neck1Input.text floatValue];
     float neck2 = [neck2Input.text floatValue];
     float neck3 = [neck3Input.text floatValue];

     (neckAvg = ((neck1+neck2+neck3)/3));
     neckAvg = roundf(neckAvg * 2.0f) / 2.0f;

     return neckAvg;
      }

 - (float)getCircumferenceValue {
     float abHipTempAvg = [self getabHipAvg];
     float neckTempAvg = [self getneckAvg];

     (circumferenceValue = (abHipTempAvg - neckTempAvg));
     circumferenceValue = roundf(circumferenceValue *2.0f) / 2.0f;

    return circumferenceValue; }
```

So yea thats my solution, there was nothing wrong with all the if/else if statements, it was the fact that dividing by 3 to get the average was giving me a much longer decimal than i needed, so by rounding them to the nearest half solved my problem. Now i get the answer that is supose to come out.

Thanks for everyones help!!

Answer (score 3):

Are you *absolutely sure* your input field outlets are all connected? Asking a nil outlet for its -floatValue would give you a nil (interpreted as 0) response.

Comment: yes they are all connected thats why its throwing me off. i just double checked again to make sure and they are connected..

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger and verified that every input and output is what you expect it to be?

Comment: No , i didnt get any errors of any kind so i didnt think i needed to.. i dont even know how to use the debugger to be honest..this is my first time using xcode so theres still alot i have to learn on it

Comment: OK. Then set a breakpoint in you code an "step over" the code. Now it's the best time to learn how to use GDB. BTW, are you sure your class hierarchy is clever? Would it be a better solution to refactor the common code of female and male classes into a common superclass to make it easier to maintain?

Comment: You absolutely *must* learn to use the debugger. No crash/exception/whatever doesn't mean no problem. Set a breakpoint on whatever action triggers all this behavior and follow it through, step-by-step, making sure to examine all the relevant variables to make sure their values are expected. The debugger is a **MUST** for every developer.

Comment: Ran out of room. Adding: Trust me, with a small investment in time and understanding, an entirely new world will open up to you in terms of figuring out problems with your code. It's like night and day.

Comment: @GorillaPatch right now this is the easiest way i know how to do what im trying to do because the males have different varriables than the females. Im sure at some point i will figure out a different maybe more efficent way to do this app, and when i do ill remake it and see how it works but right now this is all i got lol..

Comment: @Josh do i need to set a breakpoint like at the Action to calculate or does it need to be like somewhere at the start of like the - (float)getbodyfatpercentage ?? cause ive set breakpoints by accident before but didnt know what they was used for.

Comment: @Shaun Hornsby: You can set them wherever you like, as long as it's within a block of statements (putting a breakpoint outside of a function or method definition is not useful). Set your first breakpoint just before you ultimately use the value; if you find that the outlet is not connected or find some other problem, work backwards through your program towards the problem in successive debug runs.

Comment: @Peter ok thank you, i will work threw that tonite and tomorrow and see what i can come up with..will post feedback as to what i find. Thanks..

Comment: @shaun hornsby I know that designing more or less "clever" class hierarchies is complicated. Often developers first make up a too complicated class structure which is in the end harder to maintain. It is always a trade-off. Take a look at the book "design patterns for cocoa" if you want to understand the deeper principles of Cocoa.

Comment: I just went threw the debugger and im not sure if im just not setting my points right or what. but it appears to me that they are tied together as they are suppose to be. so im not sure of anything else to check.

Comment: Ok so i went and re wrote that one entire page femaleBFCinput.m thinking that i might have just typed in somethin wrong the first time. Still was getting 0 on the results page. So i went and changed one thing 
    float circumferenceTempValue To int circumferenceTempValue.. all i did was change that from a float to an int just to see what would happen and i was able to get an answer on the results screen. But it isnt the right answer because with that being an int instead of a float its not seeing anything passed the decimal in the calculations. Has anyone ran into this problem before??

Comment: seems to me that if that "circumferencevalue" being and "int" will give me an answer.. shouldnt it being a "float" give me a results as well? idk imma go threw it again and see if some of the decimals in there are conflicting with each other, thats the only thing i can think of that would cause it to return 0 is if there is more than one calculation that is the same but has different answers.. does that make sense?

Comment: ok so i dont see any conflicting numbers in there that would cause it to return 0.. anyone else got any different ideas?

Comment: im pretty sure now that my problem is due to my if/else if conditions only having 2 decimal places and the calculations im doing before that has alot more than 2 lol so i just posted a different question to figure out how to round my answers from getting the "avg's" up or down to the nearest half. That should fix my problem. Ill answer and let you all know if it does.